# Problems with Kotlin Result<T> on unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am working on an android Application and I opted to use Kotlin Result class so as to handle success/failure on my operations. I made the changes to the code, but the tests stop working and I cannot understand why. Here I show you some snippets:

**FireStoreClient.kt**

```
suspend fun items(): Result<ItemsResponse>
```

**NetworkDataSource.kt**

```
suspend fun getItems(): List<Item> =
    fireStoreClient.items().fold({ it.items.map { item -> item.toDomain() } }, { emptyList() })
```

**NetworkDataSourceTest.kt**

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Test
fun `Check getItems works properly`() = runBlockingTest {
    whenever(fireStoreClient.items()).doReturn(success(MOCK_ITEMS_DOCUMENT))
    val expectedResult = listOf(
        Item(
            id = 1,
            desc = "Description 1"
        ),
        Item(
            id = 2,
            desc = "Description 2"
        )
    )
    assertEquals(expectedResult, dataSource.getItems())
}
```

And this is the exception I am getting right now. Any clue? It appears that the fold() method is not being executed when unit testing.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Result cannot be cast to ItemsResponse

    at NetworkDataSource.getItems(NetworkDataSource.kt:31)
```

Comment: The problem is not your unit test, is the code in `NetworkDataSource.kt`. I'm not familiar with Kotlin for Android, but there's no `fold` function that receives 2 functions - https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html

Comment: Can you show what your constant `MOCK_ITEMS_DOCUMENT` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I noticed that my method of injected class which should return `Result<List<Any>>` returns actually `Result<Result<List<Any>>>` which causes the `ClassCastException`. I used the `Evaluate Expression` option for the result from the method and I got

```
Success(Success([]))
```

The app works well but unit tests didn't pass due this problem.

As a temporary solution I built a new simple implementation of `Result` sealed class with `fold()` extension function. It should be easy to replace in future to `kotlin.Result`

`Result` sealed class:

```
sealed class Result<T> {
    data class Success<T>(val value: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Failure<T>(val error: Throwable) : Result<T>()
}
```

`fold()` extension function:

```
inline fun <R, T> Result<T>.fold(
    onSuccess: (value: T) -> R,
    onFailure: (exception: Throwable) -> R
): R = when (this) {
    is Result.Success -> onSuccess(value)
    is Result.Failure -> onFailure(error)
}
```

Comment: You're right Patryk, that what I was experiencing. Thanks for your help. I've discovered [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41163) on the Kotlin project. It will be solved on 1.4.30.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a different workaround for this result-wrapping issue, for those who don't want to make their own `Result` type.

This issue appears to happens specifically when using Mockito's `.thenReturn` on `suspend` functions. I've found that using `.thenAnswer` doesn't exhibit the problem.

So instead of writing this in your unit test (changed `doReturn` to `thenReturn` here):

```kotlin
whenever(fireStoreClient.items()).thenReturn(success(MOCK_ITEMS_DOCUMENT))
```

Use:

```
whenever(fireStoreClient.items()).thenAnswer { success(MOCK_ITEMS_DOCUMENT) }
```

Edit: I should note that I was still experiencing this issue when running Kotlin 1.5.0.

Edit: On Kotlin 1.5.20 I can use `.thenReturn` again.

Answer (score 4):

After a deep dive into the problem, finally, I've found a temporary workaround that works in the testing environment. The problem is, somehow the value of the `Result` object is wrapped by another `Result`, and we can pull the desired value or exception using reflection.

So, I've created an extension function called `mockSafeFold`, which implements the `fold` behavior in normal calls, and acts fine when you are executing unit-tests.

```
inline fun <R, reified T> Result<T>.mockSafeFold(
    onSuccess: (value: T) -> R,
    onFailure: (exception: Throwable) -> R
): R = when {
    isSuccess -> {
        val value = getOrNull()
        try {
            onSuccess(value as T)
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            // This block of code is only executed in testing environment, when we are mocking a
            // function that returns a `Result` object.
            val valueNotNull = value!!
            if ((value as Result<*>).isSuccess) {
                valueNotNull::class.java.getDeclaredField("value").let {
                    it.isAccessible = true
                    it.get(value) as T
                }.let(onSuccess)
            } else {
                valueNotNull::class.java.getDeclaredField("value").let {
                    it.isAccessible = true
                    it.get(value)
                }.let { failure ->
                    failure!!::class.java.getDeclaredField("exception").let {
                        it.isAccessible = true
                        it.get(failure) as Exception
                    }
                }.let(onFailure)
            }
        }
    }
    else -> onFailure(exceptionOrNull() ?: Exception())
}
```

Then, simply call it instead of `fold`:

```
val result: Result = myUseCase(param)

result.mockSafeFold(
    onSuccess = { /* do whatever */ },
    onFailure = { /* do whatever */ }
)
```